# How to remove the composite indices for a column in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Is it possible to remove the index of the column which is part of composite indices using CSOM? I am able to remove the index of the column which is not part of the composite indices using CSOM.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the commands below, and the index column which is part of a composite column index was deleted successfully.

```
foreach ($field in $fields)  
{  
    if ($field.Indexed)  
    {   Write-Host "....Indexed Column is"  
        Write-Host $field.Title 
        $field.Indexed = $false  
        $field.Update()  
        $list.Update() 
    }  

}
```

So, I think you are trying to delete the list column, not just to delete the index of column. Is that right?

To delete the composite column index, you need to navigate to the list settings and delete it manually. Per my knowledge, we cannot use CSOM to achieve that.

Comment: If the field is having non-composite indices then I am successfully able to remove the index and delete the column, but when a field is part of the composite indices the value of Indexed property is already coming as false and when I try to remove the field, it is throwing an error like field is part of the composite indices. I think we can not remove the field from the composite indices using CSOM. We may need to do it from the UI manually.